# Getting error when using print() or summary() in pytorch to see the layers and weight dimensions in a Pytorch model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

When using print on an existing model,
it doesn't print the model. Instead it shows: 
`<function resnext101_32x8d at 0x00000178CC26BA68>`

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torchvision.models as models 
>>> m1 = models.resnext101_32x8d
>>> print(m1)
<function resnext101_32x8d at 0x00000178CC26BA68>
>>>
```

When using `summary`, it gives the following error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

```
>>> import torch
>>> import torchvision.models as models 
>>> from torchvision import summary
>>> m1 = models.resnext101_32x8d
>>>
>>> summary(m1, (3, 224, 224))
 Traceback(most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File torchsummary.py, line 68, in summary
      model.apply(register_hook)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

How to fix these issues related to `print` and `summary`? Any other ways to easily see all pytorch layers and model topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`models.resnext101_32x8d` is the class constructor, you need to call the constructor, just add parentheses at the end.

```py
m1 = models.resnext101_32x8d()
print(m1)
```

Comment: Ok. how to resolve the issue with `summary`? and does summary give different information? this works for 'print'. thanks.

Comment: `torchvision` does not have a `summary` class, you need to install and use `torchsummary` ([repo](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary)).

Comment: thanks for your response. any reason why the downvote for the question? The question seems relevant to this forum.